# Synchronizing a thread with two running threads, c++, windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, synchronization, createthread

I am a newbie in multithread programming and this is my first post here! So please bear with me.

I have two cameras which I would like to track an object simultaneously (two independent threads) and output its position to the main function or perhaps a third thread. Using the position of the object from each camera, the 3D position of the object should then be calculated. Let's say the first camera outputs *x1* and *y1*, the second camera outputs *x2* and *y2* and these should be used to estimate *x*, *y*, and *z*.

I was thinking of defining *x1*, *y1*, *x2* and *y2* as global variables so that they are easily accessible for the third thread. But the problem is that the third thread should be synchronized with the first 2 threads. The third thread doesn't change the content of *x1*, *y1*, *x2* and *y2*. It only uses these values to obtain *x*, *y* and *z*. But if the value *x1* and *y1* is updated and *x2* and *y2* are not yet updated, I want the third thread to pause until the *x2* and *y2* is updated. Or in other words, I want the third thread to use *x1*, *y1*, *x2* and *y2* that are ideally obtained at a time point *t*, or during a very short period of time.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this problem. I am thinking of using CreateThread(). Is there an easier way? 
Is it a good idea to use global variable in multithread programming?
Is it a good idea to output global variables *t1* and *t2* (system time) from thread 1 and 2 respectively, and compare them in the third thread? One problem with this approach might be that since both threads 1 and 2 are doing the same thing, it takes let's say T second for them to complete their task and therefore there is always a fixed lag between these threads which might be longer that what we want.   And as a result, thread 3 would never find *x1*, *y1*, *x2* and *y2* which are obtained very close in time!

NOTE: I am using windows 7, visual studio 2010, programming language C++.

Comment: Do you, or can you, time-stamp the arrival of the frame that is used to generate [x,y]?  Even better - can the cameras generate time-stamps on image aquisition?

Answer (score 1):

Thread 1 can SetEvent(event1) and thread 2 can SetEvent(event2). Thread 3 uses WaitForMultipleObjects to wait until both events have been set. WaitForMultipleObjects suspends the calling thread and then returns when both events are set.